# Issue with CSV as source in copy activity in adf

Tags: azure, csv, cloud, azure-data-factory

Hi I am trying to ingest data from a csv file, however during the copy activity I am getting error code that says "the name of column index 4 is empty. Make sure column name is properly specified in the header.

In my csv data I only have 3 column indexs and the header looks like this:
COL_A|COL_B|COL_C|

The delimiter is the pipe character. Is the reason this is happening because activity expects a column name after the last pipe character? Any setting I can change to resolve this issue?

I have tried changing in the source dataset the row delimeter setting to be set to Line feed but that did not change the result.

Answer (score 0):

Field delimiters are only needed between columns, not at the end of the line, that's why ADF expects a 4th column.
Your header should look like this: COL_A|COL_B|COL_C